# How to find 'r' in the NCR equation with n and answer known

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The value of $n = 105$. $\binom nr = 187460$. How do i find the value of r?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you plugged things in by hand?

Comment: Well, I guess and checked finding that r = 3 but am unsure of how to do the working

Comment: That's that. Just say $r=3$ (and $r=102$).

Comment: but is there a way to do the working out for it?

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{n}{k}$ is close to $\frac{n^k}{k!}$ when $n$ is considerably larger than $k$.

So it goes like $100,100^2/2,100^3/6\dots100^4/24$

The number you want is close to the third one and far from the other.

Also note that $\binom{n}{k}$ increases as $k$ gets close to $n/2$